# What's the difference between 'style' and 'insertRule/addRule'?

Tags: javascript, css

What is the difference?

What is the best way to work?

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets[0];
styleSheets .addRule('div::before','content:"text before";');
styleSheets .addRule('#some','color:red;font-size:14px;');  //insertRule FIREFOX
var some = document.getElementById('some');
some .style.color='red';
some .style.fontSize='14px';
some .setAttribute('style','color:red;font-size:14px;');
```

Comment: i don't think you should use either one very often. setup the css ahead of time and us js to alter attribs that activate/deactivate the CSS.

Comment: only to insert animations or clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like the difference between putting styles in a CSS file or `<style>` block, or putting them in the `style=` attribute of an HTML element. Adding a rule applies the style to all elements that match the selector. Setting `.style` of an element just changes the style of that one element, overriding styles inherited from CSS (except those with `!important` modifiers).